# ORA-00972: identifier is too long - Best strategy to avoid it in Grails

Tags: oracle, hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I am getting  "ORA-00972: identifier is too long" error while saving a domain class object.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not initialize a collection: [com.intelligrape.model.Address.studentsForPermanentAddressId#79366215]
```

What could be the possible solutions to solve this problem except reducing the length of studentsForPermanentAddressId field. The reason being, this is a legacy database table which I can not alter.

EDIT: Added the domain class description as asked by Rob Hruska

```
package com.intelligrape.model

class Address {

    String address1
    String address2
    String boxNumber
    String city
    Long stateLid
    String province
    String zipCode
    Long countryLid
    Double latitude
    Double longitude
    Long radius

    static hasMany = [studentsForPermanentAddressId: Student, studentsForLocalAddressId: Student]

static constraints = {
        address1 nullable: true
        address2 nullable: true
        boxNumber nullable: true, size: 1..25
        city nullable: true, size: 1..30
        stateLid nullable: true
        province nullable: true, size: 1..64
        zipCode nullable: true, size: 1..15
        countryLid nullable: true
        latitude nullable: true
        longitude nullable: true
        radius nullable: true
            studentsForPermanentAddressId nullable: true
            studentsForLocalAddressId nullable: true
    }
}
```

Comment: That's interesting, the Oracle's length limit is 30, and `studentsForPermanentAddressId` "only" has 29 characters.

Comment: @NullUserException - I don't think `studentsForPermanentAddressId` is the name of the actual database column; it's probably mapping to something like `students_for_permanent_...`.

Comment: @Mohd - Can you provide the domain class code that's defining the relationship in question?

Comment: Guys I have got answer to this problem over grails mailing list. Please check. http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/ORA-00972-identifier-is-too-long-Best-strategy-to-avoid-it-in-Grails-tp3815751p3815751.html

Comment: NullUser, Hibernate can sometimes generate sql with some pretty ugly joins and aliasing so if you are at 29, 30 is not hard to hit with it generating aliases so even if he is using the default naming and the column name is studentsForPermanentAddressId, it could generate sql with _studentsForPermanentAddressId0 for instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a mapping block and the existing column mappings:

```
    package com.intelligrape.model

class Address {

    String address1
    String address2
    String boxNumber
    String city
    Long stateLid
    String province
    String zipCode
    Long countryLid
    Double latitude
    Double longitude
    Long radius

    static hasMany = [studentsForPermanentAddressId: Student, studentsForLocalAddressId: Student]
    static mappings = {
         studentsForPermanentAddressId(column: 'stud_perm_addr_id')
    }
    static constraints = {
        address1 nullable: true
        address2 nullable: true
        boxNumber nullable: true, size: 1..25
        city nullable: true, size: 1..30
        stateLid nullable: true
        province nullable: true, size: 1..64
        zipCode nullable: true, size: 1..15
        countryLid nullable: true
        latitude nullable: true
        longitude nullable: true
        radius nullable: true
            studentsForPermanentAddressId nullable: true
            studentsForLocalAddressId nullable: true
    }
}
```

As an aside, if this weren't a legacy database you could use this project: http://code.google.com/p/hibernate-naming-strategy-for-oracle/

To generate correct mappings from the start.